# Many meanings of "llamas"

Tags: definiciones

Why and how has the word llama(s) 3 meanings?

- (you) call
- llama (the animal)
- flame

Comment: English is just a bad.  How about "pine" the tree and "pine" the verb?

Answer (score 22):

As to why, quite simple: three different etymological origins have resulted in the same word:

1. The verb *llamar* comes from latin *clamare*
2. The animal *llama* comes directly from a quechua word
3. The flame *llama* comes from latin *flamma*

Latin consonant groups *-cl-*, *-fl-* and others (such as *-pl-*) have frequently evolved into *-ll-* in Spanish, so these evolutions are quite normal.

As for confusing, I don't think so. It is not easy to construct a sentence where a verb and a noun could be confused. The two nouns (the flame and the animal) might be confused, but their meanings are so different that, aside from jokes or especially constructed sentences, I don't think it is very likely to happen because the context would give away the real meaning.

Comment: Llama «llama» la llama a la llama. :)

Comment: In voseo-speaking countries like Argentina is even less confusing since the first case (you call) is pronounced "llamás" (different accent).

Comment: As a side note, this can be used for puns. There was a series of ads for a phone company in the late 90's, called "la llama que llama" (it was about a llama that made prank calls, using equally bad puns)

Comment: Actually even better.  *A la llama la llama la llama «la llama»*

Answer (score -2):

When the Moores ruled in Spain, they had lookout posts on hilltops and it is said that in times of trouble they could call aid from Africa in a matter of hours by lighting the flames on top of the lookout towers, hence the connection between flame and call in Spanish.

Comment: Roger still does that.

Comment: "it is said..." sounds very questionable.  Do you have a citation to back it up?

Comment: Absolutely not. As stated in other answers, they just come from similar unrelated latin words (*flamma* and *clamare*).