# La oración con más homófonos

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, pronunciación, curiosidades

En [Many meanings of "llama"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/8192/6915) @guifa nos regala esta linda frase:

> Llama «llama» la llama a la llama.

Y recuerdo que cuando mi papá encontraba difícil alguna pregunta nos decía:

> Oh, tengo un complejo complejo de complejos.

Como me encanta este tipo de juegos de palabras, quiero pedir lo siguiente:

- Una oración gramaticalmente correcta y con sentido;
- con la mayor cantidad de variantes de **una sola palabra**, ya sean acepciones, homónimos (como "llama" y "llama") u homófonos (como "tuvo" y "tubo");
- **sin que se repita ninguna otra palabra** (la frase de las llamas no vale porque se repite "la").
- Se aceptan homófonos dialectales como "casa" y "caza".
- Se aceptan variaciones de género, número o conjugación (aunque no cuentan si la raíz no cambia el significado). Vale combinar "tuvo" con "tubos". "Tuba" podría servir si se justifica correctamente.
- Las palabras deben estar registradas en el [Diccionario de la Lengua Española](http://www.rae.es) o en el [Diccionario de Americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/). Se agradecen aclaraciones o enlaces cuando sea necesario.

Gana la oración con más **variantes** de una misma palabra, es decir, no se cuentan las repeticiones que signifiquen lo mismo.

Voy a dejar abierta esta pregunta un tiempo. Si tenemos al menos 5 respuestas, voy a entregar un premio de 100 puntos a la oración más original o interesante o graciosa, desde mi particular y subjetivo punto de vista.

---

En fin, me quedé con mis 100 puntos. (Aunque no era tan difícil, creo.)

La frase ganadora de Carlos Alejo parece insuperable, es una belleza, muchas gracias:

> Un bajo bajo canta bajo, en bajo y bajo cero los bajos del bajo bajo el bajo bajo presión.

Comment: Mi trabalenguas favorito, aunque no cumple las reglas: Si tu gusto gustara del gusto que gusta mi gusto, mi gusto gustaría del gusto que gusta tu gusto, pero como tu gusto no gusta del gusto que gusta mi gusto, mi gusto no gusta del gusto que gusta tu gusto.

Comment: Yo a eso más que un trabalenguas lo llamaría un trabamentes: es más difícil de pensar que de pronunciar...

Comment: No me resisto a mencionar la famosa frase inglesa *Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## 3 repeticiones

> ¿Que cómo como?, pues como como como.

Basada en una respuesta a [otra pregunta previa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17464/12637). Usa el verbo *comer* (tres veces) más otras dos acepciones de la misma palabra.

## 5 repeticiones

> Bajo al bajo el bajo bajo bajo presión.

Explicación:

- Bajo 1: del verbo *bajar*.
- Bajo 2: sustantivo (planta baja).
- Bajo 3: sustantivo (instrumento).
- Bajo 4: adjetivo del sustantivo previo.
- Bajo 5: preposición.

Idea obtenida de [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18171/12637). Y del comentario a la respuesta de @walen, extiendo:

> Una presa apresa su presa en la presa presa del pánico.

- Presa 1: sustantivo (privada de libertad).
- Presa 2: en realidad el verbo "apresar", pero se podría considerar homófono dado que la primera "a" se une con el final de la palabra anterior y casi ni se nota.
- Presa 3: sustantivo (cosa apresada).
- Presa 4: sustantivo (muro construido para almacenar agua).
- Presa 5: sustantivo (persona que padece algo).

## 7 repeticiones

Apelando a [las múltiples capacidades del verbo "pitufar"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17102/12637):

> Pasa que pasa cuando pasa de la raya y pasa bajo pasa pasa a ser pasa.

- Pasa 1: Verbo (suceder, acepción 52).
- Pasa 2: [Sustantivo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S4wqY0f) (uva seca).
- Pasa 3: Verbo (ir más allá de un límite, acepción 5).
- Pasa 4: Verbo (cruzar por un sitio, acepción 3).
- Pasa 5: [Sustantivo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S1z6pCC) (canalizo entre bajos por el cual pueden pasar los barcos).
- Pasa 6: Verbo (proceder a una acción, acepción 38).
- Pasa 7: [Sustantivo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S4wqY0f) (afeite para mujeres).

Con tantas repeticiones igual tiene un poco menos de sentido, pero tenerlo lo tiene.

## 10 repeticiones

Revisión de los [bajos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4oyrC6G):

> Un bajo bajo canta bajo, en bajo y bajo cero los bajos del bajo bajo el bajo bajo presión.

- Bajo 1: Sustantivo (persona con voz de bajo, acepción 32).
- Bajo 2: Adjetivo (de poca estatura. acepción 1).
- Bajo 3: Adverbio (en voz baja, acepción 40).
- Bajo 4: Sustantivo (la más grave de las voces humanas, acepción 31).
- Bajo 5: Preposición (posición inferior a la de referencia, acepción 48).
- Bajo 6 (en plural): Sustantivo (las notas que sirven de base a los acordes, acepción 33).
- Bajo 7: Sustantivo (parte musical escrita para un cantante de bajos, acepción 34).
- Bajo 8: Preposición (debajo de, acepción 45).
- Bajo 9: Sustantivo (planta baja, acepción 26).
- Baso 10: Preposición (dependencia, acepción 46).

Comment: Bravo, eres veloz. ...Pero veo solo 3 repeticiones, porque el verbo _comer_ está tres veces.

Comment: Ah, vale, entendí que se podían repetir acepciones mientras la frase tuviera sentido...

Comment: Cada vez que leo el ejemplo de 'Bajo' se me hace difícil de leer y considerar el cuarto bajo como adjetivo precediendo a otra preposición, me viene a la cabeza, 'bajo baja presión'. *prep+adj+sustantivo* pero no me parece correcto sintácticamente *bajo(adj)+prep+sustantivo*, el adjetivo funciona como adyacente del nombre sustantivo así que se sitúa delante o después del sustantivo al que se refiere.

Comment: @AlexBcn la palabra "bajo" tiene 51 acepciones entre adjetivos, sustantivos y preposiciones, seguro que se le puede sacar mucho más partido. :-)

Comment: pero como explicas un "bajo bajo" (instrumento adjetivo)? no le veo sentido al adjetivo

Comment: @BrianH. puede ser un bajo de poca altura (en comparación con otros bajos), por ejemplo (acepción 1). O un bajo de sonido grave (acepción 20), aunque sería un poco redundante.

Answer (score 6):

> *«(...) si el fecho faz gran fecho e buen fecho e bien fecho, non es gran fecho...»* (Don Juan Manuel, El conde Lucanor).

Creo que la figura a la que te refieres se llama [traductio](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traductio). O quizá, si lo que buscas son significados distintos, [antanaclasis / equívoco](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equ%C3%ADvoco).

De cosecha propia propongo esto:

> ¡Ay! Ahí hay haya, y ahí yaya halla haya.

Sé que no es exactamente lo que pides, ya que la repetición está en el fonema y no en la palabra... Pero me ha hecho mucha gracia pronunciarlo en voz alta mientras lo iba pensando jajajajaja

Comment: Del artículo de los equívocos se deduce que la presa apresa la presa en la presa.

Comment: @walen, solamente te ha faltado incluir ***aya***.

Answer (score 5):

¡Vaya, junto a la valla hay un caballo bayo que va y viene comiendo bayas!

Comment: Does _caballo_ count as well?

Comment: @mdewey No, _caballo_ does not count.

Comment: Mejor yegua baya?

Answer (score 2):

No olvidemos el ejemplo que nos enseñaron a todos en la escuela:

> Ahí hay un hombre que dice: ¡ay!

Comment: no discuto que sea correcta, pero personalmente pronuncio de forma distinta la palabras 'ahí' y 'hay', aunque obviamente si que pronuncio igual las palabras 'hay' y 'ay'

Answer (score 2):

Ya se definió la respuesta y el tiempo ha pasado pero... ¿hubiese contado una oración con homógrafos? algo de tipo 'el bote dio un bote del bote pues el tonto del bote buscaba sacar del bote y darse del bote del bote que estaba de bote en bote'... algo así como 'la *propina* se *cayó* de su *recipiente* pues el *grandisimo* tonto quería *aprovechar* y *salir rápido* del *buque* que estaba *bastante lleno*' (en cursiva las definiciones de bote, que son 6 palabras distintas con múltiples acepciones)

Comment: Está re buena. El problema es que por regla no se podían repetir otras palabas, como el _del_ que sale varias veces.